# Type error generated while using send method on a just created generator object

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, typeerror

I am trying to understand generator functions and from what I have read, the `.throw()` method is used when dealing with generators if you want to pass an externally generated value to the middle of a function, rather than at the beginning as an argument.

I created a generator function to return the smallest 1 digit palindrome, the smallest 2 digit palindrome and so on till the number of digits equal to 10.

```
    def isPalindrome(num):
        if num == int(str(num)[::-1]):
            return True
        return False
    
    def palindrome_special():
        num = 0
        while True:
            if isPalindrome(num):
                num = (yield num) - 1
            num = num + 1
    
    for number in palindrome_special():
        print(number)
        num_digits = len(str(number))
        if num_digits <= 10:
            palindrome_special().send(10 ** num_digits)
```

This code is returning a TypeError though:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/anura/PycharmProjects/Advanced Python/advanced_generators.py", line 17, in

```
palindrome_special().send(10 ** num_digits)
```

TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your logic. ```yield num``` of  ```num = (yield num) - 1``` will return `None`. Even if you fix that, the value of `num` will be always 0

Comment: @npk can you explain why None will be returned.

Comment: because `yeild num` is a statement

Comment: @npk why is the statement yield num returning None? Should it not return the .send() value 10 ** 1?

Comment: I couldn't understand the logic. But instead of `num = (yield num) - 1`, you can use `yield num; num = num-1`. Please make sure that your generator is working as expected, without the final for loop section

Answer (score 0):

You have to note that you can only pass "not None" value to the generator/coroutine if it's state is "suspended".
Generators have 4 states : CREATED - SUSPENDED - CLOSED - RUNNING

```
def coroutine():
    var = yield
    print(var)

obj = coroutine()
try:
    obj.send(4)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

In this case you'll get that error again because it's state is CREATED.
now let's try:

```
def coroutine():
    print('changing state to SUSPEND')
    var = yield
    print(var)

obj = coroutine()
next(obj)
try:
    obj.send(4)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

As you can see I first change it's state to SUSPEND using next() so that it is now ready to accept value. The execution point for the generator is now right before the 'yield' statement.

Let me add that, next() doing the same thing as send(None). So you could use `obj.send(None)` in the fist example that I wrote.